# awk to reorder lines in output file

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am printing out specific tags in the `input`. However, I can not seem to get line 2 in the current output to be line 1. It looks like because of the way the `input` is formatted that is why the `output` is ordered in the way it is. I can not seem to change it in the `awk`.  Thank you :).

**input**

```
"barcodedSamples": {"MEV37": {"barcodeSampleInfo": {"IonXpress_007": {"controlSequenceType": "", "expName": "R_2016_09_20_12_47_36_user_S5-00580-7-Medexome",
```

**awk**

```
awk -F"[]\":{}, ]*" '
    {for (i=1; i<NF; i++)   {if ($i =="expName") print $(i+1)
                             if ($i =="barcodeSampleInfo") print $(i+1) " " $(i-1)
                            }
    }
' input
```

**current output**

```
IonXpress_007 MEV37
R_2016_09_20_12_47_36_user_S5-00580-7-Medexome
```

**desired output**

```
R_2016_09_20_12_47_36_user_S5-00580-7-Medexome
IonXpress_007 MEV37
```

Comment: Any reason to parse JSON with something that's not a JSON parser ???

Comment: No reason I just am a bit more familiar with `awk` (a bit more = still learning) Thank you :).

Comment: Don't parse JSON with awk nor regex, use JQ or a language with a JSON parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

#### INPUT FILE

```
{
   "barcodedSamples" : {
      "MEV37" : {
         "barcodeSampleInfo" : {
            "IonXpress_007" : {
               "controlSequenceType" : "",
               "expName" : "R_2016_09_20_12_47_36_user_S5-00580-7-Medexome"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

#### COMMAND

```
% jq '.barcodedSamples.MEV37.barcodeSampleInfo.IonXpress_007.expName' file.json
```

#### OUTPUT

```
"R_2016_09_20_12_47_36_user_S5-00580-7-Medexome"
```

#### Or with [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) :

```
% node                                                                                                         
> j = { "barcodedSamples": {"MEV37": {"barcodeSampleInfo": {"IonXpress_007": {"controlSequenceType": "", "expName": "R_2016_09_20_12_47_36_user_S5-00580-7-Medexome"}}}}}
{ barcodedSamples: { MEV37: { barcodeSampleInfo: [Object] } } }
> console.log(j.barcodedSamples.MEV37.barcodeSampleInfo.IonXpress_007.expName)
R_2016_09_20_12_47_36_user_S5-00580-7-Medexome
```

#### NOTE

now that you understand how to access any part, just modify this a bit to fully fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

You can create one or more arrays in the BEGIN function. When processing lines do not print. Instead of printing do append to these arrays in the order you want. In the END function print out these arrays.

Comment: Thank you both very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F\" '{print $(NF - 1)"\n" $8,$4}'  file

R_2016_09_20_12_47_36_user_S5-00580-7-Medexome
IonXpress_007 MEV37
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.